# Picture blurry in android

Tags: android

Picture looks blurry when I get it from gallery.  I resize to 250w*300h using the following code:

```
        if(bm!=null)
        {
            int width = bm.getWidth();
            int height = bm.getHeight();
            float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
            float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
            // create a matrix for the manipulation
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            // resize the bit map
            matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
            // recreate the new Bitmap
            resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix,true); 
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need matrix manipulation just use

```
resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, w, h, true);
```

I am not sure how do you calculate newWidth and newHeight, but it could be that your new scaled bitmap is too small and then streaches in a view hence blurred.